# SoapUI: 5.6.0 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PostgreSQL/org.postgresql.Driver when running tests using maven

Tags: postgresql, maven, soapui

I'm trying to run SoapUI tests by using mvn commands, and I keep seeing this exception in every JDBC request, although the tests pass and the database is accessed."

The dependency for PostgreSQL is added in maven.

Log:

```
5:20:54,484 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] running step [Check db to make sure it was removed]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: PostgreSQL/org.postgresql.Driver
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:398)
        at com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils.registerJdbcDriver(GroovyUtils.java:103)
        at com.eviware.soapui.support.jdbc.JdbcUtils.initConnection(JdbcUtils.java:50)
        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.JdbcSubmit.getDatabaseConnection(JdbcSubmit.java:190)
        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.JdbcSubmit.prepare(JdbcSubmit.java:222)
        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.JdbcSubmit.runQuery(JdbcSubmit.java:173)
        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.JdbcSubmit.run(JdbcSubmit.java:147)
        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.JdbcSubmit.<init>(JdbcSubmit.java:79)
        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.JdbcRequest.submit(JdbcRequest.java:122)
        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.JdbcRequestTestStep.run(JdbcRequestTestStep.java:194)
        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.runTestStep(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:211)
        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCaseRunner.runCurrentTestStep(WsdlTestCaseRunner.java:47)
        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:138)
        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestCaseRunner.internalRun(AbstractTestCaseRunner.java:46)
        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestRunner.run(AbstractTestRunner.java:128)
        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestRunner.start(AbstractTestRunner.java:76)
        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCase.run(WsdlTestCase.java:594)
        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestCase.run(WsdlTestCase.java:78)
        at com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.TestCase$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
        at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:7)
        at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:90)
        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.WsdlTestSuite.runTearDownScript(WsdlTestSuite.java:495)
        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestSuiteRunner.internalFinally(WsdlTestSuiteRunner.java:163)
        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.testcase.WsdlTestSuiteRunner.internalFinally(WsdlTestSuiteRunner.java:46)
        at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.support.AbstractTestRunner.run(AbstractTestRunner.java:149)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
15:20:54,589 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Assertion [JDBC Status] has status VALID
15:20:54,589 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Assertion [JDBC Timeout] has status VALID
15:20:54,592 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Assertion [XPath Match] has status VALID
15:20:54,595 INFO  [log] Teardown script finished.
```

pom.xml:

```
<properties>
        <soapui-maven-plugin.version>5.6.0</soapui-maven-plugin.version>
        <postgreSql.version>42.2.20</postgreSql.version>
    </properties>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>SmartBearPluginRepository</id>
            <url>https://rapi.tools.ops.smartbear.io/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Plugin to read external properties file -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version><!-- afaik it's final, no need for parameter -->
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>initialize</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <files>
                                <file>project.properties</file>
                            </files>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <!-- SoapUI plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
                <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${soapui-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                
                <configuration>
                    <printReport>true</printReport>
                    <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                    <outputFolder>${baseDir}/target/surefire-reports</outputFolder>
                </configuration>

                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
                        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
                        <version>${postgreSql.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
```

Note: left groupid and executions out.

Any idea what can cause the exception, or how to suppress it? What is weird for me, it's that the JDBC requests run without an issue.

Comment: The JDBC connector seems missing from `bin/ext` as explained in the [documentation](https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/testing/data-driven/tutorials/jtds/driver.html).

Comment: If the connection is successful, it is not using the JDBC Smartbear connection which the initialize step of GroovyUtils is using.

Comment: @ConstantinKonstantinidis that isn't it, because I run it using mvn commands, it's independed of the SoapUI installed locally. Also, I tried having the ext folder within the repository with the driver, and it doesn't work.

Comment: In SoapUI there is no such exception thrown at all. Only while running tests with maven.

Comment: Registering the driver might be useless if SmartBear runs headless with a parameter like --Djava.awt.headless=true added to the maven command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Java a JDBC driver can be loaded automatically from classpath, that is why it still works.

I think there is a line in your Groovy teardown script that looks like this:

```
def driver = 'PostgreSQL/org.postgresql.Driver'
```

If you replace it with

```
def driver = 'org.postgresql.Driver'
```

it should work fine.

---

UPDATE: The questioner solved it by adding also this line to the script:

```
com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils.registerJdbcDriver(driver)
```

This is kind of a hack, but it made the Exception go away.

Comment: There is no such line, I even tried adding it in the setup script, and the exception is still thrown.

Comment: The problem is that `PostgreSQL/org.postgresql.Driver` is not a valid classname and must be replaced by `org.postgresql.Driver`. Please lookup also your **JDBC request test step**, maybe it is configured there as **Driver** option?
(from: https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/functional/steps/jdbc-request.html)

Comment: I am using the open source version. I don't have the configurations tab. I'm looking to see if there is a workaround.

Comment: @AdrianPop the UI is a bit more limited in the open source version, but still you can configure a JDBC request test step. Double click or right click + "Open Editor", you will find a field "Driver" in the "Configuration" section.

Comment: Your first answer was mostly what I was looking for. I had to also register the driver in order to get rid of the exception. 
I added this line as well, and it worked. **com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils.registerJdbcDriver(driver)**

Comment: Apparently due to the apache jog4j update that they did with 5.6.1, this 'hack' doesn't work anymore. Trying to find a solution.

Comment: Update: cleanly reinstalling and adding the postgresql jar file to both the lib and bin/ext folders in the soapui installation folder, the issue was resolved.

Comment: For me (MacOs Sonoma 14.3), ONLY adding to the $SOAPUI_INST/lib folder worked. Adding to $SOAPUI_INST/bin/ext had no effect.